# GND and pin 17 shorted

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, microprocessor

I was carrying out a continuity test on micro chips with part no. [BU2092F](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/logic_switch/serial_parallel/bu2092f-e.pdf) and realised that pin one (GND) and pin 17 (OE#) are shorted. The chip is on the motherboard and I tested it with a multimeter. Hoewever, the pin 17 is not connected to any line on the mother board. I have checked the data sheet but there was no indication that it should be so. Is this normal in some chips?

Comment: If it is soldered on a PCB, yes. Otherwise, no. Please tell more about the situation. With what you measured and how?

Comment: refer to the datasheet for info about the OE# input

Comment: The chip is on the motherboard and I tested it with a multimeter.Hoewever, the pin 17 is not connected to any line on the mother board. I have checked the data sheet but there was no indication that it should be so. Is this normal in some chips?

Comment: Perhaps you don't see the connection to GND, the pin might be on a via.

Answer (score 1):

It’s an output enable line. For the chips to do their job, the output needs to be enabled. In many simple applications, there is no need to ever disable the output, so it can be tied to ground, as it’s an active-low signal.

The trace to the ground runs to a via or ground area under the chip, most likely.

So, most likely what you see is perfectly normal.